# Firebase Hosting Deployment via creating image or running image in container?

Tags: angular, firebase, docker

I'm looking to deploy my Angular app to Firebase Hosting. I've set up the repository on Google Cloud Repository.

I've set up a trigger which builds Image from Dockerfile.

Here's my `dockerfile`:

```
FROM johnpapa/angular-cli

WORKDIR /home/angularapp
# COPY . .
COPY package.json ./
# RUN npm install && ng build --prod --aot --progress=false
RUN npm install npm@latest -g
RUN npm install -g firebase-tools
RUN npm install
COPY . /home/angularapp

RUN ng build --prod
RUN firebase deploy --token mygentoken
```

If I build this Image, the app is deployed to Firebase.

My question is: what's the best practice here?

Should I use `CMD` and run the image in a container and do `ng build --prod && firebase deploy` inside the container or is this approach okay?

Since my app is independent (doesn't need outside resources), It does not need to run in a container (Kubernetes pod) I think.

In the current scenario, the Image is built and also deployed.

I used this to automate my deployments.